# add dynamic lib in iphone application

Tags: iphone

How do I add dynamic libraries in iphone xcode? I want to add the lib: "libcrypto.dylib" ( in /usr/lib ). Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple does not support dynamic linking (*edit: to your own libraries*) on the iPhone. You can, however, statically link OpenSSL and libcrypto. A precompiled static library and example Xcode project using it are found here: http://github.com/x2on/OpenSSL-for-iPhone